# Problem on fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> John's front lawn is $\dfrac13$ the size of his back lawn. If John mows $\dfrac12$ of his front lawn and $\dfrac23$ of his back lawn, what fraction of his lawn is left unmoved?

How to solve it without picking numbers?

The way to solve with number picking:

> (size back lawn) = $6$ units
>
> (size front lawn) = ($\dfrac13$)(size back lawn) = $2$ units
>
> (size total lawn) = (size back lawn) + (size front lawn) = $8$ units

Now we can use these numbers to calculate how much of each lawn has been mowed:

> Front lawn:  $(\frac 12)(2) = 1$ unit
>
> Back lawn:  $(\frac 23)(6) = 4$ units

So, in total, $5$ units of lawn have been mowed.  This represents $\dfrac58$ of the total, meaning $\dfrac38$ of the lawn is left unmowed.

Comment: Instead of using $6$, just use $x$.  Go through the same motions, but instead of manipulating $6$ you algebraically manipulate $x$.  It acts just like any other number, the only difference is that you can't simplify it immediately during each step, but that is fine.

Comment: That, is pretty much what algebra is all about, and it's motivation comes from wanting a general form rather than individual substitution, as you have done.

Comment: Once you realize that the back yard is 3 times as big as the front yard and therefore the backyard is 3/4 the total and the front yard is 1/4, it follows that 1/2x1/4 + 1/3x3/4 = 1/8 + 1/4 = 3/8 is unmowed.  But there's nothing wrong with "picking numbers" or using algebra.  In fact I'd recommend it over what I just described in this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let John's lawn be $J$. Then, John's front lawn would be $\dfrac 14J$ and his back lawn would be $\dfrac 34J$.
>   If he is mowing $\dfrac 12$ of his front lawn and $\dfrac 23$ of his back lawn, then he is mowing $$\frac 14J \cdot \frac 12+\frac 34J \cdot \frac 23=\frac{5}{8}J$$ If $\dfrac 58J$ was mowed, you can see that $\dfrac 38J$ was not mowed.

Although I wouldn't know why you would want to do it this way; picking numbers is a lot easier.

Comment: Because it is not immediately obvious that the answer doesn't depend on the initial size of the lawns.  Going through the algebra we see that that's the case.  In future or more complicated problems, that isn't always going to happen.  Furthermore, it isn't always particularly easy to pick "nice" starting numbers.  It so happened that the numbers he picked simplify nicely, but had he started with $7$ or $10$ he'd have messy fractions to deal with.

Comment: @JMoravitz True; generally I do picking numbers as my first option though.